# Typeahead 0.9.3 autocomplete remote doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, laravel-5, typeahead.js

I'm using typeahead for an autocomplete field. When I use option remote like explained here: https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me
It shows all entries and not the subset it should show.
Here is the js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#palettenNummerEinlagerung').typeahead({
    name: 'nummer',
    remote:'http://192.168.0.108/paletten/nummer_eingelagert'
  });
});  
</script>
```

And the serverside action for the JSON which should be received remotely:

```
public function getPalettennummerEingelagert(){
    $result=\DB::table('paletten')
    ->leftJoin('einlagerungen', function ($join) {
        $join->on('paletten.id', '=', 'einlagerungen.palette_id');
    })
    ->whereNotNull('einlagerungen.palette_id')
    ->whereNull('einlagerungen.entahmedatum')
    ->where('nummer', 'LIKE', '%'.\Input::get('q').'%')
    ->select('nummer')
    ->get();
    $returnArr=array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
    {
            $returnArr[]=''.$result[$i]->nummer.'';
    }
    return json_encode($returnArr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `remote` to `prefetch`:

```
prefetch:'http://192.168.0.108/paletten/nummer_eingelagert'
```

As described in [this GitHub typeahead.js issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/248):

> After thinking more on this i realized that it has to be
>   responsibility of remote api to return filtered results, not the
>   typeahead. Since i was using static json datasource my returned
>   results are same every time for which one should use prefetch. So
>   closing this issue.